# Teleporting mobs 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map where mobs will follow / tp to you, is there an way to do this with commandblocks?? I am making the map in 1.12.2 because I am more familiar with command.

Comment: If this isn't easy or possible, it can also be increasing the range from mobs to see you.

Comment: In what way are you more familiar with 1.12 commands? You're asking how to teleport entities to the player, which is one of the most basic commands (except if I misunderstand your question, then please elaborate). I would recommend reading or watching a somewhat recent command tutorial.

Comment: They don't need to be tp'd to the player, they need to follow the player. So the player needs to run away from it

Comment: You mean walking at their regular speed? You didn't ask that, you even specifically said "tp to you". Also, hostile mobs already do that, what specifically is it that you want differently?

Answer (score 1):

This command teleports all mobs with that type.
There's probably a tutorial out there, like Fabian said it is one of the most basic commands.
/tp @e[type=minecraft:creeper] playername

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have mobs follow the player around the map.

IIRC, you can do this with:

1.12-

```
/execute @e[type=!Player] entitydata @s {Attributes:[{Base:1000d,Name:"generic.FollowRange"}]}
```

1.13+

```
/execute as @e[type=!Player] run data merge entity @s {Attributes:[{Base:1000d,Name:"generic.FollowRange"}]}
```

This will make all mobs in a 1000 block radius around you follow you (if they can see you).

This may be wrong, I'm on mobile right now, will check later today.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the following command in a repeating command block:

```
/tp @e[type=(insert_mob_type_here)] (insert_player_name_here)
```

Or you could use

```
/tp @e (insert_player_name_here)
```

I know that this works for 1.14, 1.15 but u dont know if it will work for 1.12, but I hope it helps.

(P.S. you should be more specific, because some mobs can tp to you already and hostile mobs already follow you, you dont have to use commands, but you can adjust follow range, speed, and persistence. And if u want to make custom mobs with custom values there are generators out there, like digminecraft and mcstacker)